# Issue with the dequeue function in the custom class

Tags: python, c, cpython, pyobject

I am building a RingBuffer class for my module. However, I am facing some issues with the dequeue function. When I enqueue/dequeue integers, everything is fine. When I enqueue a list, the first dequeue operation returns an empty list instead of the actual values. When I enqueue a string, the first dequeue operation returns meaningless data that says:

```
''_builtins__'
```

and then if I continue to dequeue, or call any methods, it gives an error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the enqueue/dequeue functions:

```
static PyObject *
RingBuffer_enqueue(RingBuffer *self, PyObject *args)
{
    // its only works with integers, solve that and make it work with any type
    PyObject *item = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &item))
        return NULL;

    // if its full, overwrite the oldest item
    if (self->size == self->capacity)
    {
        Py_DECREF(self->items[self->head]);
        self->items[self->head] = item;
        self->head = (self->head + 1) % self->capacity;
    }
    else
    {
        self->items[self->tail] = item;
        self->tail = (self->tail + 1) % self->capacity;
        self->size++;
    }

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyObject *
RingBuffer_dequeue(RingBuffer *self)
{
    if (self->size == 0)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;

    PyObject *item = self->items[self->head];
    self->items[self->head] = NULL;
    self->head = (self->head + 1) % self->capacity;
    self->size--;

    return item;
}
```

and here's the RingBuffer type

```
typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD;
    long capacity;
    long size;
    long head;
    long tail;
    PyObject **items;
} RingBuffer;
```

what is the problem that I cannot see? thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be missing a lot of refcount management, plus you forgot to update the tail when you add an element at full capacity.

Comment: thanks for the tail, how can i correct the other problem? can you please generate an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is a borrowed reference. If you're going to keep a reference to the appended item, you need a new reference:

```
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &item))
    return NULL;
Py_INCREF(item);
```

Aside from that, you also forgot to update the tail when you add an element at full capacity. Plus, in case an element tries to interact with the queue on `Py_DECREF`, you should decref the old element once you're done updating the queue, instead of while you're still in the middle of messing with it:

```
if (self->size == self->capacity)
{
    PyObject *old_head = self->items[self->head];
    self->items[self->head] = item;
    assert(self->head == self->tail);
    self->head = self->tail = (self->head + 1) % self->capacity;
    Py_DECREF(old_head);
}
```

Comment: you are a genius :) thanks! I want to ask you something, I am trying to get familiar with the Python source code and C API, which resources do you suggest? Thanks in advance.